# Can this be written as a function?

Tags: r, performance, function, for-loop

I have this code in my procedure which i repeat several times. Can it be written as a function?

```
position <- numeric()
gen <- newgen <- matrix(0,nrow=2,ncol=6)
gen <- matrix(c(sample(100,12)),nrow=2,ncol=6)                 
cum <- c(0.1860595, 0.2510327, 0.2912947, 0.4893581, 0.5803205,1)
Random <- runif(6, 0, 1)    
for (i in 1:6){
         position[i] <- min(which(cum > Random[i]))
         newgen[,i] <- gen[,position[i]]
}
newgen
```

Comment: Put all your code in `function_name <- function() { ......}` ?

Comment: You really should put spaces around `<-`. That makes your code so much more readable. And you can write everything as a function in R.

Comment: @MrJames When you repeat your code each time, is it exactly the same? Or what changes each time?

Comment: @RonakShah thanks for the suggestion but can the for loop be eliminated in the function for effective performance?

Comment: @Ben newgen changes each time.